# error url using django and rest framweork

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Error when I try to call some id endpoint for my urls.

For example, the view in rest_framework:

[image]

I try to enter `http://127.0.0.1:8000/categoria/4` or 5 and I see an error.

```
The current path, categoria/4, didn't match any of these. (error 404)
```

I am using the rest_framework for this.

file urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^doctor$', views.DoctorList.as_view()),
    url(r'^doctor(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.DoctorDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^paciente$', views.PacienteList.as_view()),
    url(r'^paciente(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.PacienteDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^categoria$', views.CategoriaList.as_view()),
    url(r'^categoria(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.CategoriaDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^examen$', views.ExamenList.as_view()),
    url(r'^examen(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.ExamenDetail.as_view()),
     path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))   

]
```

Comment: You missed `/`, url(r'^categoria/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.CategoriaDetail.as_view()),

Comment: Probably need to put that line above the one above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help in your case:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^doctor$', views.DoctorList.as_view()),
    url(r'^doctor/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.DoctorDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^paciente$', views.PacienteList.as_view()),
    url(r'^paciente/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.PacienteDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^categoria$', views.CategoriaList.as_view()),
    url(r'^categoria/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.CategoriaDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^examen$', views.ExamenList.as_view()),
    url(r'^examen(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.ExamenDetail.as_view()),
     path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))   

]
```

You should check for exact pattern - `categoria/<regex>` but you missed the **slash** before regex. Hope this helps.

Comment: ty , broh that is the answer , problem fixed thy people :D

Comment: Glad it helped :)